# Why is my Traffic Light code not working?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have finished coursework; this is for experimental purposes.

I'm trying to create a successful traffic light sequence. However, when I click the button, the first image of the sequence remains the same.

Why is it not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  
<h1>Traffic Lights Task 3 JavaScript Controlled Assesment 2017</h1> 
<p>This is  my Traffic Light script</p> 

<img id="Traffic_Lights" src="RED.png">
<button type="button" onclick="changeTraffic_Lights()">Change 
Lights</button>  

<script> 

    var image = []
    image[0] = "RED.png";
    image[1] = "AMBERRED.png";
    image[2] = "GREEN.png";
    image[3] = "AMBER.png";

    function changeTraffic_Lights() {

    var Traffic_Light_Sequence = document.getElementById('Traffic_Lights');

      if (Traffic_Light_Sequence.src == "RED.png") {
      Traffic_Light_Sequence.src = image[1];
    } else if (Traffic_Light_Sequence.src == "AMBERRED.png") { 
      Traffic_Light_Sequence.src = image[2];
    } else if (Traffic_Light_Sequence.src == "GREEN.png") {
       Traffic_Light_Sequence.src = image[3]
    } else {
      Traffic_Light_Sequence.src = image[0]

     }
     }

  </script>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes:

1) you need to put the script in the header, otherwise the onclick function won't know the function ahead of time.

2) Traffic_Light_Sequence.src returns the full path, so you'd need to use the full path in your example.  However, a better way would be to use placeholder variables.  E.g., define a new var called "light_state" or something and use its value 0,1,2,3 to determine the logic of changing the image.